# JS: window.onerror, how to get the url?

Tags: javascript

I am using

```
window.onerror = function (msg, url, line)
```

to catch global javascript errors. It's working, but I am not able to receive the correct URL because I am loading pages in DOM per AJAX. So the URL is always my base-url like "localhost".

Is it possible to receive the correct URL of the file which causes the error like "localhost/myScriptWithErrors.js"?

Comment: Not globally, no. Maybe you could keep track of the `XMLHTTPRequest` objects you use for your requests and add error handling locally to these objects?

Comment: That would be a neverendig story because I am using ASP.NET MVC framework with multiple partial views each containing some javascript. But thank you for your comment - I will have to think of another solution or just leaving JS error handling apart.